# WP: два ajax-поиска на странице для разных типов записей

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Несколько типов записей (post + произвольные).

Должно быть два поиска: один ищет внутри одного типа записей, второй - внутри всех остальных, кроме первого.

Соответственно, форм для поиска на странице 2. Поиск живой, т.е. ajax.

Есть идеи/плагины/решения для такого случая?

Answer (score -1):

Идея такая - делаете 2 формы, и 2 ajax-запроса через wp_query для каждой формы. В `wp_query` задаете нужный `post type`.

Comment: Было бы круто, если бы вы добавили немного кода для примера)

Comment: Вам минус поставили, потому что это больше похоже на комментарий, а не на ответ.